# add cells in UICollectionView from bottom to top using Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a Chat screen using UICollectionView in Swift 4.2. I've done it.
I want to improve it by making the cells grow from bottom to top instead of top to bottom (while keeping the order of messages too). Any help? I've tried searching for it, still unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: You can try to set top content inset that will make the first message to appear at the bottom and modify the inset when a new message is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make collection view height constraint outlet for it and calculate your cells height after that you can set height of collectionView. and one case will come of maximum height, your collection height will equal from screen height with calculate space your navigation and input textview.

Comment: Calculate your total cells height and subtract from collectionview height after that set your top inset.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way would be to flip the collection view and its cells:-

```
cv.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

Doing this will just flip your CollectionView's content and won't require you to handle anything, I guess

**EDIT**:-

For your requirement, you shouldn't be appending elements to your array. You should insert new objects as the first element of the array(the data source):-

```
myArray.insert(element, at: 0)
```

In order to get the right order, you can just reverse the array

Comment: Thanks! Issue with rotations is that a new cell is added with its content inverted, plus a new cell is added to the top of rotated screen instead of getting added in the bottom and as I said I need to preserve the order of cells.

Comment: Good answer. As far as I know, many of the iOS chat list UI's made in this way.

Comment: One drawback to this solution is that, if you implement pull to refresh using a UIRefreshControl, the user will need to instead *push* the collection view *up* to refresh, and the refresh control will be at the bottom.

Comment: can you fix the jump of content offset while not at bottom on new inserts?

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the top inset of the collection view as the `collectionView` reloads.

Call this after calling reloadData():

```
func updateCollectionContentInset() {
    let contentSize = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    var contentInsetTop = yourCollectionView.bounds.size.height

        contentInsetTop -= contentSize.height
        if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
            contentInsetTop = 0
    }
    yourCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInsetTop,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
let diff = collectionView.frame.height - collectionView.contentSize.height
if diff > 0 {
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: diff, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```